# java web application get client printers

Tags: java, powershell, web

I have a java web application.

My app needs the client printers name. 
we used PowerShell file to get that

```
String vCommand = "powershell -executionpolicy bypass  -File ".concat(aPrintersScript).concat(" ").concat(vHostName);
Process vProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(vCommand);
vProcess.getOutputStream().close();
```

this is not giving us the remote client printers, it returns the server printers.

I run the web app on the intranet , and have user permissions.

what can I do to get the remote client printer names?

thanks, Tami

Comment: What kind of Java web application? Is it browser-based?

Comment: Take a step back. Does your powershell command work on the windows command line?

Comment: first thing first, you need printer name of client machine programitcally, that is not a best solution. second change of approach is needed , you are giving the option to print,just give a button of print and invoke print window i.e. when you press `CTRL+P` a window gets opened up , user choses the printer he want to print the document and proceed think in this manner not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

It's logical for the PS cmd to return the server's own printer list as you're running the command within the context of the server machine where the web application is running.

In general I don't see how this way of retrieving the information is going to work for remote machines (since there is no chance of this working remotely). My best take on resolving this, is to either have an endpoint on the client which will allow the server to perform a GET on and thus retrieving the printer information or alternatively you could have a process that exports this information from the client side over to the server side.

Comment: can you please explain how to  create a process that exports this information from the client side over to the server side ? or how to perform GET  to retrieve the printer information ?

Comment: In order to do you need to provide some more information regarding the architecture of both your server side application and/or the client side.

Comment: we us tomcat 7 as server , client may vary